# What plaintext editor with math symbols integration is available?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, text, unicode

I am looking for a text-editor with full unicode-math support. Plaintext math entered and rendered properly. I am not expecting typographical features and symbol-repositioning like LaTeX, but at least render the symbols linearly. And of course input method for it, so I do not need to copy and paste.

Is there such an app available? (anywhere, not just repositories)

Note: I do know about OpenOffice, LibreOffice, Word, TeX, LaTeX, MathML, etc; but I want plaintext!

[This webapp](http://math.typeit.org/) is the closest that I could find.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *Character Map* plugin in **gedit**. To enable it, go to *Edit > Preferences > Plugins* and enable *Chararcter Map*. You might have to enable *Side Panel* too. For that just use the shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image: CharacterMap]

You might want to select *Common* from the list.

Answer (score 0):

The best editor are `VIM`, `Emacs` and `Gedit`. All with unicode support. There are so many plugins available for them to do such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Although designed as a journal, in [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) you combine without any effort [txt2tags](http://txt2tags.org/) markup, LaTeX and html. I mean, you don't need to type anything but your equations as in LaTeX, or your Unicode characters, or whatever you wish.